Bootable USB not showing in Boot Menu
I recently purchased a Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen5 with Windows 11 preinstalled and am trying to install Fedora Sway Spin. I've tried creating a bootable USB with the Fedora ISO using Fedora Media Writer, Rufus, and Balena Etcher. However, the bootable USB does not appear as an option in the boot menu when I press F12 during reboot.
I've already tried disabling Secure Boot, but it hasn't made a difference. Before this issue, I was able to see and boot from the USB as USB-HDD when I used Fedora Media Writer, but I didn't install Fedora because of a checksum error (which I read can occur when creating the USB on Windows).
Unfortunately, after a BIOS update via Lenovo Vantage on the same day, the USB no longer appears as a boot option. The BIOS update seems to me like the only thing that might have changed between when the USB was recognized and now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

CFC errors can happens in any OS, with any media, with any tool. You should try another USB stick. That's likely the problem and not anything else you mentioned

I've just tried with another USB stick, but I still have the same problem :(

Of course makes sure the ISO itself isn't corrupt. It goes without saying that if the ISO is corrupt nothing else matters.

Well, it shouldn't be corrupt as I've downloaded and burnt the ISO using Fedora Media Writer.

File corruption has to do with the download and/or the state of the filesystem where it was saved. Of course it could be fine, just try in another computer if available.

What file system is the USB? Many PC's cannot boot from other than FAT32, and some large drives come with other formats.

@ChanganAuto unfortunately I don't have another computer available at the moment.

@DrMoishePippik I don't know exactly what file system Fedora Media Writer writes on the USB as there is not option to configure it. Though, I'm sure that, when I tried with Rufus, it wrote FAT32.
